# How to convert quote data to order book data using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, trading

Good day,

I have a data set on trading and quote data with timestamps and I would like to convert this data into the top level of the order book at those specific times.

Below is an example of the data and the desired output and I am struggling to do this in R efficiently using dplyr. I think it might be possible to iterate across each line item, but the data set is massive, so this approach is not computationally feasible.

```
original = data.frame(
  TimeStamp = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  OrderID   = c(1,2,2,1,1,1,3,3),
  msgType2 = c("Add","Add","Modify","Modify","Modify","Cancel","Add","Cancel"),
  Side2 = c("BUY","SELL","SELL","BUY","BUY","BUY","BUY","BUY"),
  Quantity = c(1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,NA,200,NA),
  Price2 = c(25422,25492,25493,25421,25443,NA,25463,NA),
  BidPrice = c(25422,NA,NA,25421,25443,NA,25463,NA),
  BidVol = c(1000,NA,NA,1000,1000,NA,200,NA),
  AskPrice = c(NA,25492,25493,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  AskVol = c(NA,1000,1000,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  CancelPrice = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,25443,NA,25463),
  CancelVol = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,400,NA,200)
)

desired = data.frame(
  TimeStamp = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  OrderID   = c(1,2,2,1,1,1,3,3),
  msgType2 = c("Add","Add","Modify","Modify","Modify","Cancel","Add","Cancel"),
  Side2 = c("BUY","SELL","SELL","BUY","BUY","BUY","BUY","BUY"),
  bestBidVol = c(1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,600,200,600),
  bestBid = c(25422,25422,25422,25421,25443,25443,25463,25443),
  bestAsk = c(NA,25492,25493,25493,25493,25493,25493,25493),    
  bestAskVol = c(NA,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000)
)
```

Timestamp is unique and each OrderID can only be a BUY or SELL. Buy orders would feed the bid side, while sell orders would feed the ask side of the order book respectively. Furthermore, each order can either be an Add, Modify or Cancel.

In my example, I have a partial order cancellation for OrderID = 1 and then also a new order entering the order book (ID = 3) that was then cancelled. These would need to be captured accordingly in the top level of the order book.

In the case of the ID = 1, the original order was for volume of 1000 and there were a couple price modifications, until 400 volume was cancelled so only 600 volume remains in the order book. In the case of ID = 3, the buy order was at a higher price that the current best bid, so it went to the top of the order book with its corresponding volume of 200 but was then subsequently cancelled so the ID = 1 went back to being the best buy order.

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't the cancel in OrderID=3 (TimeStamp 8) reduce the bestBidVol? Also did you switch CancelPrice and CancelVol in original?

Comment: Yes you are right, I did switch price & volume, will edit this now. Adding ID = 3 means it goes best bid with volume at 200. So when that order is cancelled its essentially no longer in the order book so you have to revert to the next best order (ID = 1)